# Why does using this. not let me compile my dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH8XM.png)it says
Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

code

```
                this.LobbyWindow = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(10f, 80f, 100f, 20f), this.LobbyWindow, "page one");
```

Comment: Wherever that code is it's `static` so you can't use `this` because there's no instance of the class. You might consider supplying enough context if you want a more specific answer, but the error is *very* clear.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword specifically refers to the current instance of the current type. In a `static` method, there is no current instance so obviously `this` must be invalid. You cannot access instance members in a `static` method. If `LobbyWindow` is an instance property then you would have to have a reference to an instance of that type in order to set the property on that instance. That reference would have to be accessed via some other `static` member, e.g. a field, or else passed to the method via a parameter.